# Multiprocessing faild to run

Tags: python, multithreading, process, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm learn python multiprocessing, with below code in jupyter notebook. But it cannot execute the sub process task function `download_task`, and only output something like `0.11.` with no error.

While when I copy this code to online python executer, it works OK.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid
from random import randint
from time import time, sleep

def download_task():
    time_to_download = randint(5, 10)
    print("befor sleep")
    sleep(time_to_download)
    print("after sleep")
def main():
    start = time()
    p1 = Process(target=download_task)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=download_task)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end = time()
    print('%.2f.' % (end - start))

main()
```

---

Here is screenshot of the jupyter notebook execute result:,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding `()` after function name.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid
from random import randint
from time import time, sleep

def download_task():
    time_to_download = randint(5, 10)
    print("befor sleep")
    sleep(time_to_download)
    print("after sleep")
def main():
    start = time()
    p1 = Process(target=download_task())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=download_task())
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end = time()
    print('%.2f.' % (end - start))

main()
```

If you're running on terminal, you will see the error message:

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'download_task' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Apparently, by using only `download_task`, it was treating `download_task` as an attribute of main, instead of a function.

Comment: It's works, but I don't figure out the reason here.

Comment: I can't pinpoint the exact reason, but it has something to do with Windows, which I assume you're using.

Comment: This docs has some info on it, take a look: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Comment: Yes I'm using windows.